# How to improve performance of geoprocessing

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

We are using ArcPro and are having some trouble with performance. For example:

```
IGPResult res = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("management.AddField", Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(args.ToArray()));
```

takes 5 seconds or more when adding a single field for a node and at least 1 second when adding a single field for a link. This results in a single function taking 45 seconds to call and most of that time is spent adding fields (10 seconds for adding 2 fields for nodes and 7 seconds for adding 4 fields for links).

I saw on the esri site (https://community.esri.com/thread/197606-performance-of-geoprocessing) where someone else had the same issue, but there was no reply. Has anyone else experienced this and have a possible solution? Also, why the time discrepancy between nodes and links? I would think that links would take faster since there is more information associated with a link.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else has this, I improved performance greatly by removing inspectors and replacing them with cursors (huge performance improvement) and found a way to add multiple fields at once (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-fields.htm). Removing inspectors (new in Arc Pro) resulted in the biggest performance gain.